# Do bitwise operations resolve to constant values

Tags: c++, variables, bit-manipulation, constants

I was just wondering if someone knew if bitwise ANDs and ORs aswell as bitwise shifts operating on constants gets pre-calculated by the compiler to constant values.

For example `int Foo = Bar / ( 1 << 12 )`

The reason I do that instead of `Bar >> 12` is that if Bar is a negative value it goes down to -1 not zero.

Comment: Any decent compiler would be able to calculate constant expressions (i.e. expressions containing only constant values) during compilation as an optimization. Not only bitwise expressions, but others too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"I was just wondering if someone knew if bitwise ANDs and ORs aswell as bitwise shifts operating on constants gets pre-calculated by the compiler to constant values."*

Yes the

```
( 1 << 12 )
```

part will be evaluated at compile time.

It's effectively the same as writing

```
int Foo = Bar / 4096;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even the lamest compiler is going to do simple constant folding like that. Really, you would probably implement that in a Compilers course in University, that's the level it's on.

Compilers do things that seem silly to us humans occasionally, usually "big picture" things that it could not detect. But compilers are great at this type of thing where it only needs some locally available information, where it can look at a small part of the internal representation of the code and match it to some known pattern. Two well-known examples of that are constant folding and strength reduction.

So you can really expect more here, that division should go away. There is a well known (in compiler building circles anyway) recipe to follow to turn division by a constant into (roughly, ignoring details) a multiplication and a shift, and there's an even simpler recipe for division by a known power of two (this case!)

GCC on -O2 turned this:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x / (1 << 12);
}
```

Into this:

```
lea eax, [rdi+4095]
test    edi, edi
cmovns  eax, edi
sar eax, 12
ret
```

No left shift, no division. It adds 4095 to non-positive numbers to make them round the right way.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe no left shift, but looks like right shift to me `sar eax 12`... +1 is from me anyway.

Comment: @doc well yes, it has to divide somehow

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can use 'constexpr' to compel the compiler to do the calculation in constant expression in compile time

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to know whether your compiler can compute a constant integer value at compile time (without using `constexpr`), try using the computed value as the size for a C array.

```
int arr[Bar / ( 1 << 12 )];
```

If it compiles, you know it succeeded because C array sizes must be constant at compile time.